# DualBoot CM7 and CM9 for HTC Desire Z?

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-desire-z, dual-boot

I want to be able to switch from CM7 to CM9 and vice versa without losing my apps and data everytime. Is it possible to make a dualboot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a dual boot is possible, there's a nice app for that end available from Google Play Store.

[Boot Manager Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.drx2.bootmanager) <sup>(2,17€)</sup> and the [Boot Manager Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.drx2.bootmanager.lite) <sup>(free)</sup>, both from [Init 2 Winit Apps](http://www.init2winitapps.com/).

> Boot Manager is Android's first multi-boot application. It allows you to install boot ROMs from your sdcard and boot between then with just a reboot. The application acts as your recovery for your sdcard slots. Install your kernels, themes, and ROMs all through the app and use your normal recovery for your phone ROM only.

[image: Boot Manager Loading] [image: Boot Manager ROM selection] [image: Boot Manager Settings]

Unfortunately, I haven't found any supporting information if this will or will not share apps between ROMs, but at the very least it solves the dual boot problem.

**Ps:**
Since apps when installed on the SDcard still leave a portion of their code on the main installation directory of the current ROM, it doesn't seen possible to have apps shared across different ROMs.

Comment: I'll try this now!

Comment: This actually soft bricked my phone, I had to flash it again with CM7, so I'll just deal with one ROM :)

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen Consider also emailing the developer and let him know about your device, in order to have him providing better support in future releases.